# MIPS: How to calculate the new value of the PC

Tags: mips

For example:

If PC is 0x2000FFFF and address in the jump instruction is 0x0000111,
what is new value of the PC?

Can someone please explain to me how I'd calculate this?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Well the program counter holds the address for the next instruction right? So am I just adding 0x0000111 to the current PC 0x2000FFFF?

EDIT2: This is a jump instruction, not branch.

Comment: 0x2000FFFF + (0x0000111 <<2)

Comment: Are you asking about a branch or a jump?

Comment: Well the program counter holds the address for the next instruction right? So am I just adding 0x0000111 to the current PC 0x2000FFFF?

Comment: If you mean the absolute jum `j` or `jl` then it's completely different from branch instructions which jump relatively to the current address

Comment: Yeah, a jump instruction.